# ionic 2 get data from malformed json

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ecmascript-6, ionic2

is there anyway i can get this malformed json format which is odd i have no control over this json manually so i need to get this data and manipulate it with rxjs observable from http get

```
{
  "firstNm": "Ronald",
  "lastNm": "Mandez",
  "avatarImage": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/74.jpg"
}

{
  "firstNm": "Ronald",
  "lastNm": "Mandez",
  "avatarImage": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/74.jpg"


{
  "firstNm": "Ronald",
  "lastNm": "Mandez",
  "avatarImage": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/74.jpg"
}
```

Comment: You would have to, before using .json() method, threat this (the response) as an string, then use some regex (or other approach) to remove this commas before each } and add a coma after each } (but not after the last)  and then use JSON.parse() to tranform it to a valid JSON.

Comment: threat it as string ?  i would love to know how

Comment: response.text() is that how i should threaded as string ?

Comment: @benabdo 
    let badJSON = JSON.stringify(response);

then see my answer below and you should be good

Comment: Is it just the commas that are missing? Is that second closing `}` really missing or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: that json looks like that exactly as you can see

Comment: ok, wasn't sure because that `}` used to be there before your last edit.

Comment: my bad the last commas i took them off at the beginning cause it was a copy/past error now the json that you see is the correct one is bunch of objects

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your JSON in the console and this seems to work.  In the map function I've used you can probably implement more generic replacement methods to alter the strings, but it works for this example.

```
function fixBadJSON(response){
let badJSON = JSON.stringify(response); // added this edit in case you don't know how to get the response to a string
let arr = badJSON.split('}\n');  // Looks like the JSON elements are split by linefeeds preceded by closing bracket, make into arr length of 3
let fixedArr = arr.map((item)=>{  // map the array to another, replace the comma at the end of the avatarImage key.  elements in array should be proper JSON
    if(item[item.length] != '}') item += '}';  //put the brackets back at thend of the string if they got taken out in the split, probably a better way to handle this logic with regex etc
    return item.replace('jpg",','jpg"')
});
let parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fixedArr));
return parsedJSON 
}
```

Take the JSON data you've posted up there and copy it to a variable as a string and test the function, it will return a properly formatted array of JSON data.

Call that when you get a response from your service to transform the data.  As far as the observable chains and any async issues you might be seeing those are separate things.  This function is just designed to convert your malformed JSON.

Comment: That's very hard to read as there's no indentation there, but don't bundle the logic to change the response inside your http observable call.  It's two separate issues.

Take the code above, and wrap it in a function :
 
    fixJSON(badJSON){
       //... what I wrote above
       // add this at end
      return parsedJSON
}

then call that function in your http method so it returns the transformed result

Comment: I'm going to edit my response answer a little so you can see that it's a function, maybe that'll help.  Check it in 5 minutes

Comment: @benabdo I edited my response.  Basically, just try to test that function with the dummy data you presented in the example, if it works, that issue is solved - then the issue becomes are you calling it properly in the context of your http request, which is a different issue entirely - as part of coding is breaking problems into smaller ones.   It's a new question, and maybe doesn't have to be answered in this thread

Comment: @benabdo did your JSON change in the example?  It isn't a one size fits all solution, so having the right JSON up there is crucial to get an accurate response

Comment: thank you i understand very well, one thing is that there is no commas at the end avatarImage key, im trying right now to implement it and see if it works thank you so much

Comment: the problem is how can i implement it with observable  @chairmanmow